# Getting null while parsing JSON using jq in shell script

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I'm parsing below `JSON` using `jq` in my shell script, but I'm getting `null` while parsing this field `config.subtype`. And I want to check if `config.subtype` value is `mobile`, I want to update the value as `1000` for this field `config.price` and print the complete JSON. What I'm doing wrong here and how to update the existing JSON field value.

Appreciated your help in advance! Thanks!

Please find my code below:

**test.json**

```
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "product": {
        "config.type": "electronics",
        "config.count": "5",
        "config.subtype": "mobile",
        "config.price": ""
    }
}
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
#

    result=$(cat test.json| jq '.product.config.type')
    echo $result
```

Comment: Use `jq '.product."config.type"'`

Comment: You were close, 

    $ res=$(cat test.json | jq '.product."config.type"')
    $ echo $res
    $ "electronics"